# How to delete junk strings appearing in an integer column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of integers (sample row: `123456789`) and some of the values are interspersed with junk alphabets. Ex: `1234y5678`. I want to delete the alphabets appearing in such cells and retain the numbers. How do I go about it using Pandas?

Assume my dataframe is `df` and the column name is `mobile`.

Should I use `np.where` with conditions such as `df[df['mobile'].str.contains('a-z')]` and use string replace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your junk characters are not limited to letters, you should use this:

```
yourSeries.str.replace('[^0-9]', '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.Series.str.replace`:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['125109a181', '1361q1j1', '85198m4'])
s.str.replace('[a-zA-Z]', '').astype(int)
```

Output:

```
0    125109181
1       136111
2       851984
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the regex character class `\D` *(not a digit)*:

```
df['mobile'] = df['mobile'].str.replace('\D', '').astype('int64')
```